# how to generate time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, analytics

I want to generate time series data logged every 50 ms in a csv file using R for 48 hours.

I tried the following, without success

```
x<-Sys.time()
x
# [1] "2015-12-05 08:00:29 EST"
x.ts <- ts(x, start=1, freq=2)
x.ts
# Time Series:
# Start = c(1, 1) 
# End = c(10, 1) 
# Frequency = 2 
# [1] 1449317249 1449317249 1449317249 1449317249 1449317249 1449317249
# [7] 1449317249 1449317249 1449317249 1449317249 1449317249 1449317249
# [13] 1449317249 1449317249 1449317249 1449317249 1449317249 1449317249
# [19] 1449317249
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try this:

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2015-12-05 08:00:29.000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
end   <- as.POSIXct("2015-12-07 08:00:29.000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")

x <- seq(start, end, by=0.05)
```

Comment: good idea (it uses the seq.POSIXt function - see "?seq.POSIXt")